# How to stop WordPress using utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci collation?

Tags: database, encoding, collation

Recently I've installed PHP7 on my MAMP and updated to newest version of WordPress. Every time I do a new site all my tables are using collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

I have tried setting `define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');` in my wp-config.php which worked fine until Gravity Forms ignored it and created all it's tables in `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

I've seen that if `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is available it will use that so is there a surefire way to stop WP using that collation? Can I just remove that collation as I am having to run 10 ALTER TABLE queries before I can port the database over to staging/live server?

Comment: Should there be a good reason for this? Why do you have to convert?

Comment: Gravity forms is powerful, but do you need it? If you do, maybe your system should support it.

Comment: bumping this. I have the same problem. My local machine has a higher version of MySQL. I used to be able to do a sync of DB to deploy my sites. Now because of the different collation, I can't sync anymore. This is a huuuugge problem.

Comment: I have the same issue while developing locally. Pushing up to my live database is always a pain because it never likes that collation.

Comment: If this is an issue specific to the plugin, then you should open up a ticket on the WordPress.Org page for the plugin.

Comment: Yes, how the f__k can we make wordpress create utf8mb4_unicode_ci instead of utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci????

Answer (score 3):

Not using utf8mb4_unicode.... collation and using a utf8 one instead is a security problem. The right answer is to upgrade your sites and DBs so they all use utf8mb4

Comment: There are also other problems I've encountered:  [oEmbeds containing invalid chars aren't always cached if the meta_value column's charset is utf8 and not utf8mb4](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36456). That's pretty problematic for busy sites ;-)

Comment: yes, forgot about emoji not working

Comment: this is not a thing about utf8 vs utf8mb4, it's about utf8mb4_unicode_ci vs utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Comment: you are partially right @Stratboy, but the essence is actually running different versions of DB between production and development, something you should not do, especially if you wish to be able to migrate content.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while deploying sites using BackupBuddy. Ninja Forms was constantly creating tables in unicode_520_ci, no matter what settings I used in Sequel Pro.

Not sure if this helps or not, but all I had to do was change the collation within Sequel Pro for the specific Ninja Forms tables, and then the deployment would work as normal.